# Accessing my Gmail account without going through Google sign in and not remember password

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

I cannot access my Gmail account inbox Access please help me

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score -1):

If you have forgotten the password to your Gmail account, don't worry. Google understand that the standard send-email-wth-verification-code approach doesn't work here because, well, you've forgotten your email password! Instead, you can go to the [Google Account Recovery Page](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery), where you'll be asked questions like "We'll send an email to your recovery email address, ********1234@gmail.com," or "Can you remember when you created your Google Account?" They understand this happens and are very good about it.

Unfortunately, if you can't get your password back, you're done. Google is *incredibly* secure and there is almost certainly no way you can get in unless you can recover your password. Good luck!